# mysqli_set_charset() can't find connection

Tags: php, mysqli

I previously used `mysql_set_charset()` but now as I changed to mysqli, I tried to use `mysqli_set_charset()` but it seems like it can't find my connection.

my connect.php

```
   <?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'audiologiska_kliniken');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Ett fel inträffade [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
```

my Database.php

```
<?php

include 'c:/wamp/www/mvc/include/connect.php';
class Database
{

    protected $mysqli;

    function __construct(mysqli $db)
    {
        $this->mysqli = $db;
    }
}
```

My Display Model:

```
{
    function getData() {
        mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8'); //Warning: Undefined variable 'mysqli'
```

Comment: You have a scope problem. The version of `$mysqli` you are using in `GetData()` is local to that function (and therefore not initialised) and different from the version in your `DataBase` class. How you'd get at the version in your `DataBase` class is not obvious since you've protected it. You'd have got away with this with `mysql_*()` since that API assumes the last opened database connection if none is specified. `mysqli_*()` isn't as forgiving.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the object-oriented connection but procedural `mysqli_char_set()` function, use `->set_charset()` like this:

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

```
mysqli_set_charset($this->mysqli, 'utf8');
```

Comment: If anything: `$this->mysqli`, no second `$`.